# Pass form field names to bind parameter at class instance

Tags: php, reflection, binding, prepared-statement

I'm using a factory(class) to present forms from a target database table - as defined at class instance.  Then on submit, create a new instance of the class which then insert a new record in to the database.  $_POST key names match the table column names.

My issue is dynamically assigning bind parameters when the variables are determined at class instance.  I'm getting the following, whether I use Reflections method or inline.

```
 Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables
```

The following method is called in the sub class after the post array has been contructed and assigned to the class property $array.

```
  private function addrecord($array,$tbl,$_conn){

   //define field name array for query statement
   foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
   $keyarr[]=$key;
   }

//BUILD THE QUERY STATEMENT
$query = "INSERT INTO $tbl SET ";
  foreach ($keyarr as $key){
    $query .= ($key."=?, ");    //clone and add next element
  }
$query = rtrim($query,", ");    //remove EOL whitespace and comma
//done

 /*
//Hard code bind parameters works as expected
if (self::$_conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_UNAME,DB_UPWORD,DB_NAME)){
$stmt=self::$_conn->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$array['user_id'],$array['user_name'],$array['user_email'],$array['user_date'],$array['user_active']);
$stmt->execute();
$insertid=$stmt->insert_id;
$stmt->close();
echo "The record was created with id ".$insertid;
}
 */

  //Tried re assigning post array as reference
  //same error as just passing $array
  //$array = $this->refValues($array);

 //Binding params using Reflections, same error 
 self::$_conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_UNAME,DB_UPWORD,DB_NAME);
 $stmt   = self::$_conn->prepare($query);
 $ref    = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt');
 $method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param");
 $method->invokeArgs($stmt,$array);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
 self::$_conn->close();
 }

//Pass By Reference required for PHP 5.3+, dev server 5.3.17
function refValues($arr){
   if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0){
   $refar = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
      $refar[$key] = &$arr[$key];
      return $refar;
    }
   return $arr;
```

}

Thanks in advance and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, mysqli is practically unusable with prepared statements.
So, I'd  suggest you to either use PDO or, better, some intelligent library that can make safe query without prepared statments.
With such a library your function will be written in one line

```
private function addrecord($array,$tbl){
    $this->conn->query("INSERT INTO ?n SET ?u", $tbl, $array);
}
```

please note that if $array is coming from the untrusted source, you have to filter it's content out first.

Comment: +1 for common sense answer.  Switch the insert query process to PDO and works as expected. Thanks for the common sense.

Answer (score 0):

Per Common Sense, changed process to PDO.  Works as expected.  Should have done it sooner.  Only issue remaining is UI feedback.  Would like to return an insert id, however MySQL doesnt return a last insert id for PDO.  And again, the class doesnt know the tables structure in advance so hard coding in not an option.  Need a workaround.  Any thoughts?  Heres the new insert process using PDO.

```
 try{
   self::$_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.'', DB_UNAME, DB_UPWORD);
   $stmt = self::$_conn->prepare($query);

   $arcount=count($array);  //set number of bindParam loops
     foreach($array as $key=>$value){
   $stmtarr[]=$value;   //convert assoc to numerated array
}
 //re index array so increment will match up with placeholder position
 $stmtarr = array_combine(range(1, count($stmtarr)), array_values($stmtarr));

 for($i=1;$i<=$arcount;$i++){ //bind variable, one for each placeholder, 
$stmt->bindParam($i,$stmtarr[$i]);
 }
 $stmt->execute();

 } catch (PDOException $e){
print "Error: ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
die();
 }
```

Assume everything else is the same as above.

Comment: you don't need no binding. just `$stmt->execute($array);` and PDO returns insert id all right.

Comment: hmm, let me try that out then. But then I'm not optimizing input anywhere else.  I assume that (input optimization) process is lost if I execute on the $array with out binding first, is that right?